# Confusion regarding usage of "know" and "understand"

Tags: word-usage, ielts

In the following sentence, which word should be used: "understand" or "know"?

*I do think it is important for us to try to understand/know different cultures*

The actual answer and even I guessed that 'understand' is the correct word to fill in, but I am not sure why 'know' can't be used here?

Comment: But it *can* be used. Which is used depends on what you're trying to say.

Comment: @JasonBassford I am also not sure about the context. I just got this question in my exercises book, they didn't give any further details. I think it is just about which one is more appropriate to use and I feel "'understand" fits better into this. Am I correct?

Comment: As @Jason wrote, "know" can be used in this sentence. "Know"and "understand" are different verbs, and with each one the sentence has a different meaning. Neither one is more appropriate or fits better than the other, unless there is some context that requires a specific meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do think it is important for us to try to understand/know different cultures

The answer is "understand".

The phrases "try to figure something out" and "try to understand something" are idiomatic. They are common expressions, and correct.

On the other hand, "try to know" is not idiomatic in the same way. For example "I am trying to know what to do" doesn't sound right. In many cases, you either "know" or "don't know", but you don't "try to know".  Rather, you would try to figure it out, or try to learn, so then you could say "Now I know it."

You could say "Trying to *get to know* somebody".

If you remove "try", the choices are:

> I do think it is important for us to understand/know different cultures

Even here, "know" is not exactly right.  It should be *"know about"*.

Comment: This is the answer which I was looking for. Thanks @Sam. Appreciate the way you described and made it very much clear to me.